# $VIMINIT conflicts for neovim and vim

Tags: neovim, viminfo, lunarvim

*Repost from stackoverflow after suggestion*

I am trying to move from vim to neovim. I have a strange problem.

I have, in my .bashrc, exported $VIMINIT to `.config/vim/vimrc` so that vim files like `.viminfo` are not polluting my home folder. This trick was suggested in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286866/how-to-tell-vim-to-store-the-viminfo-file-somewhere-else) and if I remember correctly, it was only thing that actually removed all `.vim*` files out of my home directory.

But neovim also seems to give priority to $VIMINIT over its own config folder. I cloned lunarvim as .config/nvim and upon launching neovim, it wasn't using it. Only after I commented out the export statement from my bashrc file, it detected its config folder.

I don't want to remove my well tested vim setup without getting comfortable with neovim first. What is a safe and appropriate way to separate neovim and vim? I want to have .config/vim and .config/nvim as config location for settings and generated junks respectively and not have any related dotfiles in home folder.

**Update:**
Based on @martin-tournoij suggestion, currently this is setting in my viminit proxy file

```
let g:nvim_path='~/dotfiles/editors/nvim'
let g:vim_path='~/.config/vim'

if has('nvim')
    " let g:runtimepath += '~/.config/nvim/'
    execute 'set runtimepath+=' . g:nvim_path
    execute 'set packpath+=' . g:nvim_path . '/plugins'
    execute 'source '. g:nvim_path . '/init.lua'
    finish
else 
    execute 'source '. g:vim_path . '/vimrc'
    finish
endif
```

Any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: The Stack Overflow post you link to doesn't mention `VIMINIT` anywhere. That said, `VIMINIT` is "used as an Ex command line", so you could just check for Neovim in it and source a different file. Or you could write a wrapper for neovim: `nvim () ( unset VIMINIT; nvim "$@"; )` or `alias nvim='env -u VIMINIT nvim'`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a "distribution" like lunarvim—you will have a far better time actually learning and customizing the editor to behave the way you want. Note that the first initialization found is used, so `VIMINIT` blocks, say, vimrc files (`:help VIMINIT`). A better solution might be to use `-i` or set `'viminfofile'` if that was your only concern. (There's also `'undodir'`, `'directory'`, `'backupdir'`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Vim and Neovim will use the same `VIMINIT` environment variable to set the configuration directory, so setting a global one will apply to both.

You have two options:

1. Set it only for `vim` commands, or unset it for `nvim` commands:

   ```
   alias vim='VIMINIT=.config/vim/vimrc vim'
   # or:
   alias nvim='env -u VIMINIT nvim'
   ```
2. Source a different file in your vimrc if neovim loads it:

   ```
   if has('nvim')
       source ~/.config/nvim/vimrc
       finish
   endif
   ```

   To get a full separation you also need to tweak some other paths here as well, such as `runtimepath` and `packpath`. It's actually a bit complex how this all works.

I recommend the first option as it's *a lot* easier and keeps a clean separation between the two.

Comment: Follow-up on your second technique, Suppose, I set VIMINIT as `~/.config/vim/viminit`
and within that file, I simply write conditional sourcing, `if has('vim') source .config/vim/vimrc else if has ('nvim') source .config/nvim/init.vim`   

Will this work, keeping all my configuration file and folders at their respective place and sourcing based on condition.

Comment: There is no `has('vim')` @AbhinavKulshreshtha and it will always be "false", but you can use `if has('nvim') [..nvim..] else [..vim..] endif`. It should work, but things like custom syntax files, after/ directory, and plugins will be shared between Vim and Neovim, which may be what you want, or it may not be.

Comment: The if-else technique works. I pointed VIMINIT to a vim_proxy file which contains the if else condition pointing to respective rc files. Now I have both lunarvim and my old vim setup working as expected. 

Can you elaborate your point about runtimepath and packpath for full complex separation? Do you know a repo which I can look at for reference?

Comment: can you please check the vim_proxy file I updated on the question and give me suggestion to improve full separation?

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha; the way vim works with all these paths is a bit complex and I don't remember things off-hand, so I don't really know. If you want "full separation" then not setting VIMINIT for both is by far the easiest and most fool-proof.